# IE11 not initiating CORS request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cors

By fiddling it seems IE11 does not make an ajax request if it is cross origin. FF and Chrome will at least make the request and throw an error if the resource API is not sending necessary headers. The resource API (Web API 2.0) in my case is [adding required headers](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors) which will be helpful IF IE makes the request, but it doesn't.

**Client's JavaScript:**

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.fn.somePlugin = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl + '/articles/list/',
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true
    }).done(
        function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log('hello world!');
        });
    return this;
}
```

The ajax request above works perfectly in Chrome and FF but not in IE11.

I've tried:

1. adding a reference to [XDomainRequest.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.2/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js) without any effect.
2. enabling cross origin request in IE Security options - even though it seems bizarre to do this on every client machine. Regardless, it made no difference.

Comment: I just tried this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get on IE 11 and it works. Problem lays somewhere else.

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki I'm using jQuery $.ajax and $.getJSON methods. Don't want to change all my code to plain XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki also, I don't see where you're making a cross origin request in your sample code.

Comment: Is it possible that the data is cached in IE, so it is not making the request for that reason?  You could try putting a date time param on the call to bust the cache.

Comment: @JohnKoerner clearing all cache almost every time when trying the request.

Comment: documenting some links here for future reference: IEInternals: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx CORS support in browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors Web API:http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Comment: @greatbear302 I'm seeing something similar where my [API requests from localhost to my Intranet are not made using IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27072572/186778). Are you noticing this on requests originating from localhost by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I was unable to retrieve any CORS data using XMLHttpRequest(), $.ajax() or $.ajax shortcuts. The problem turned out to be localhost (IIS WinPro7). Every AJAX CORS request was preflighted which generated an

> Origin http://localhost not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

error, followed by

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied

When I moved the HTML page to a webserver it worked fine.