# API requests from localhost to Intranet not made using IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-domain, cors, fiddler

I have an application running on localhost that makes HTTP requests to a CORS-enabled Web API hosted on my Intranet. All api requests are successful using Chrome and Firefox, but I never see them in the IE 11 dev tools or Fiddler. Using Chrome and Firefox I can see the Origin header is set as expected. If the application is running on the Intranet (still a different domain from the api), the calls are successful using IE11. I've also gone through the Internet Options in IE and believe everything is set appropriately.

I'm hoping someone can either point out something obvious I'm missing or confirm that IE is broken and I just need to forget about it and move on.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682581/ie11-not-initiating-cors-request and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/84ad7b98-b3c1-43bb-9cb6-c5810016d63b/ie11-not-initiating-cors-request?forum=iewebdevelopment but haven't got any response. After reading several articles I concluded there is inconsistency between browser manufacturers and was forced to host the API under the same domain so it satisfies same origin policy. In my case I could do that. If you cannot, make a proxy caller class in the client application that makes HttpWebRequest

Comment: If the requests weren't seen in Fiddler, they weren't sent. It's likely due to the fact that IE restricts cross-zone sends. You *should* see a notice on the CONSOLE tab in the F12 developer tools.